# jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2 in IE9 dies on first call

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, compatibility

I have a div that I'm cloning over to a div, the div is originally hidden and has some other attributes that I change.

Anyone have a sugestion why it fails on first call in IE quirks mode and on second one it works?

`$("#TRtemplate").before($("#TRtemplate").clone().show().removeAttr("id").css('background-color', color));`

Any hints are more then welcome, thy and arigato and hvala unapred and domo arigato and dankeschon :p

Comment: Is there a possibility that you can put this in a jsFiddle so we can see?

Comment: It's failing in quirks mode. In what way is it failing? is it not being shown? is an error being thrown? and why are you working in quirks mode?

Comment: I am debuging it so it works in all versions of ie.... quirks mode is a must for that. And sadly no, this is a part of a giant site which is to big to put in there.

Comment: Hy guys just to reply why it died. Sorry for the delay... im pretty busy on the job. It was a false html comment in an eval function call insite a plugin i made... sheesh ie is a wuss....